# Find nearest preceding and following dates between data frames

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following two data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A","A","B","B","C","D","D","D","E"),
             Date = as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-12 08:56:00","2018-04-13 11:03:00","2018-04-14 14:30:00","2018-04-15 03:10:00","2018-04-16 07:28:00","2018-04-17 11:17:00","2018-04-17 14:21:00","2018-04-18 09:56:00","2018-05-02 07:49:00")))

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("A","A","A","B","C","D","D","D","D","D","E"),
              Date = as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-10 07:11:00","2018-04-11 18:59:00","2018-04-12 12:37:00","2018-04-15 01:43:00","2018-04-21 09:52:00","2018-04-15 20:25:00","2018-04-17 12:33:00","2018-04-17 14:21:00","2018-04-18 10:59:00","2018-04-20 14:11:00","2018-05-01 09:50:00")))
```

For df1, I would like to do 2 things:
First, I want to find the nearest preceding date, by ID, from df2. 
Second, I want to find the nearest following date, by ID, from df2, again without repeating values. In both cases, I do not want dates from df2 to be repeated in df1.

Using the roll = Inf feature from the data.table package I am able to merge in the preceding dates by ID.

```
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

setkey(df1, ID, Date)
setkey(df2, ID, Date)[, PrecedingDate:=Date]

result <- df2[df1, roll=Inf]
```

I'm unsure of how I can pull the nearest following date from df2 into df1, and how I can ensure that dates are not repeated.

The result should be as follows:

```
result <- data.frame(ID = c("A","A","B","B","C","D","D","D","E"),
                     Date = as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-12 08:56:00","2018-04-13 11:03:00","2018-04-14 14:30:00","2018-04-15 03:10:00","2018-04-16 07:28:00","2018-04-17 11:17:00","2018-04-17 14:21:00","2018-04-18 09:56:00","2018-05-02 07:49:00")),
                     PrecedingDate = as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-11 18:59:00","2018-04-12 02:37:00",NA,"2018-04-15 01:43:00",NA,"2018-04-15 20:25:00","2018-04-17 14:21:00",NA,"2018-05-01 09:50:00")),
                     FollowingDate = as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-12 02:37:00",NA,"2018-04-15 01:43:00",NA,"2018-04-21 09:52:00","2018-04-17 12:33:00","2018-04-17 14:21:00","2018-04-18 10:59:00",NA)))
```

Any help here would be most appreciated.

Comment: what happens if `df2` has the same date as `df1`? Is it classified as preceding or following or ignored?

Comment: In those instances, it should be classified as only preceding.

Comment: The 2nd `PrecedingDate` and the 1st `FollowingDate` in `result` are incorrect imo. They should be both `2018-04-12 12:37:00`. I've corrected that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `dplyr`. You might get some warnings for `min` `max` functions but you can safely ignore or suppress them.

```
library(dplyr)

closest_to_zero <- function(x) {
  neg <- which(x == max(x[x < 0]))
  pos <- which(x == min(x[x > 0]))
  c(previous = neg, following = pos)
}

result <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "ID") %>%
  group_by(ID, Date.x) %>%
  mutate(
    time_diff = Date.y - Date.x,
    Preceding = Date.y[closest_to_zero(time_diff)["previous"]],
    Following = Date.y[closest_to_zero(time_diff)["following"]]
  ) %>%
  distinct(ID, Date.x, Preceding, Following)

# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   ID, Date.x [9]
  ID    Date.x              Preceding           Following          
  <fct> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 A     2018-04-12 08:56:00 2018-04-11 18:59:00 2018-04-12 12:37:00
2 A     2018-04-13 11:03:00 2018-04-12 12:37:00 NA                 
3 B     2018-04-14 14:30:00 NA                  2018-04-15 01:43:00
4 B     2018-04-15 03:10:00 2018-04-15 01:43:00 NA                 
5 C     2018-04-16 07:28:00 NA                  2018-04-21 09:52:00
6 D     2018-04-17 11:17:00 2018-04-15 20:25:00 2018-04-17 12:33:00
7 D     2018-04-17 14:21:00 2018-04-17 12:33:00 2018-04-18 10:59:00
8 D     2018-04-18 09:56:00 2018-04-17 14:21:00 2018-04-18 10:59:00
9 E     2018-05-02 07:49:00 2018-05-01 09:50:00 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
df1[, PrecedingDate := df2[df1
                           , on = .(ID, Date <= Date)
                           , .(ID, Date = i.Date, pd = x.Date)
                           ][, .SD[.N], by = .(ID, Date)
                             ][shift(pd) == pd, pd := NA][, pd]
    ][, FollowingDate := df2[df1
                             , on = .(ID, Date >= Date)
                             , .(ID, Date = i.Date, fd = x.Date)
                             ][, .SD[1], by = .(ID, Date)][, fd]][]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df1
>    ID                Date       PrecedingDate       FollowingDate
> 1:  A 2018-04-12 08:56:00 2018-04-11 18:59:00 2018-04-12 12:37:00
> 2:  A 2018-04-13 11:03:00 2018-04-12 12:37:00                <NA>
> 3:  B 2018-04-14 14:30:00                <NA> 2018-04-15 01:43:00
> 4:  B 2018-04-15 03:10:00 2018-04-15 01:43:00                <NA>
> 5:  C 2018-04-16 07:28:00                <NA> 2018-04-21 09:52:00
> 6:  D 2018-04-17 11:17:00 2018-04-15 20:25:00 2018-04-17 12:33:00
> 7:  D 2018-04-17 14:21:00 2018-04-17 14:21:00 2018-04-17 14:21:00
> 8:  D 2018-04-18 09:56:00                <NA> 2018-04-18 10:59:00
> 9:  E 2018-05-02 07:49:00 2018-05-01 09:50:00                <NA>
> ```

This is equal to the desired result:

```
> all.equal(df1, as.data.table(result))
[1] TRUE
```

---

Used data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A","A","B","B","C","D","D","D","E"),
                  Date = as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-12 08:56:00","2018-04-13 11:03:00","2018-04-14 14:30:00","2018-04-15 03:10:00","2018-04-16 07:28:00","2018-04-17 11:17:00","2018-04-17 14:21:00","2018-04-18 09:56:00","2018-05-02 07:49:00")))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("A","A","A","B","C","D","D","D","D","D","E"),
                  Date = as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-10 07:11:00","2018-04-11 18:59:00","2018-04-12 12:37:00","2018-04-15 01:43:00","2018-04-21 09:52:00","2018-04-15 20:25:00","2018-04-17 12:33:00","2018-04-17 14:21:00","2018-04-18 10:59:00","2018-04-20 14:11:00","2018-05-01 09:50:00")))
result <- data.frame(ID = c("A","A","B","B","C","D","D","D","E"),
                     Date = as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-12 08:56:00","2018-04-13 11:03:00","2018-04-14 14:30:00","2018-04-15 03:10:00","2018-04-16 07:28:00","2018-04-17 11:17:00","2018-04-17 14:21:00","2018-04-18 09:56:00","2018-05-02 07:49:00")),
                     PrecedingDate = as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-11 18:59:00","2018-04-12 12:37:00",NA,"2018-04-15 01:43:00",NA,"2018-04-15 20:25:00","2018-04-17 14:21:00",NA,"2018-05-01 09:50:00")),
                     FollowingDate = as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-12 12:37:00",NA,"2018-04-15 01:43:00",NA,"2018-04-21 09:52:00","2018-04-17 12:33:00","2018-04-17 14:21:00","2018-04-18 10:59:00",NA)))
```